# How to redirect Spring configuration error handling to my custom one?

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-security, configuration

I was wondering if there was a clever way to handle exception in Spring through the configuration. I can throw exception directly from a class that extends the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter interface, but It seems to me I cannot send message with it if I use the exceptionHandling method. But if I remove the conf I can't do a global custom exception configuration. I was wondering if Spring could redirect exception handling to a @ControllerAdvice?

for now my code look like this (I removed the useless part from the code)

**The configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@FieldDefaults(level = PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthFailureHandler authFailureHandler;

private static final RequestMatcher PUBLIC_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("**", "OPTIONS"), // allow prefligh for now in debug 
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/public/**")
);
private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new NegatedRequestMatcher(PUBLIC_URLS);

TokenAuthenticationProvider provider;

SecurityConfig(AuthFailureHandler authFailureHandler, final TokenAuthenticationProvider provider) {
    super();
  this.authFailureHandler = authFailureHandler;
  this.provider = requireNonNull(provider);
}

@Override
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
}

@Override
public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS);
}

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS)
             .and()
            .authenticationProvider(provider)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS)
            .authenticated()
          
}
```

Here the code that handle the exception is

```
 .exceptionHandling()
            .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS)
             .and()
            .authenticationProvider(provider)

            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS)
            .authenticated()
```

The problem is if i raise an exception, it is handle by the default ExceptionHandling and I cannot set custom error messages or http error code, resulting in a default error handling. If I remove it i have to raise exception everywhere!

**A controller**
One in many, but like this you have a sample

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/public/users")
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@CrossOrigin
public class UserPublic {

@NonNull UserAuthenticationService authenticationService;

@PostMapping(value = "/login",
      consumes="application/json",
      produces="application/json")
UserDTO login(@RequestBody shortDTO dto) throws UserNotFoundException {

  UserDTO userDTO = authenticationService.login(dto.email, dto.password);
  if (userDTO == null) throw new UserNotFoundException("no User found with this email / password combination");

  return userDTO;
}
```

**The exception**

```
 public class UserNotFoundException extends Exception {


 public UserNotFoundException(String no_user_found) {
   super(no_user_found);
 }
```

}

**The ExceptionHandler**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ServiceExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler  {

  @ExceptionHandler(value = {UserNotFoundException.class })
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
  public ApiErrorResponse unknownException(Exception ex, WebRequest req) {
    System.out.println("damn here we go again");
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return new ApiErrorResponse(ex.getMessage());
  }
}
```

**StackTrace with the conf enable or disable is**

```
com.application.controller.user.UserNotFoundException: no User found with this email / password combination
....
```

but with the conf I receive 403 error instead of 500 (will change but wanted different code for error) and the body is empty.
How can I combine both ? I have the same problem for protected routes and I don't want to handle exception in each function in each controller if the user is logged and let Spring do it for me, just redirect it to my custom exception Service.
Thks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your ExceptionHandler Advice You need to wrap ApiErrorResponse into ResponseEntity and return new ResponseEntity<>(new ApiErrorResponse(ex.getMessage()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to work. But why can't i send directly an object of my conception ? What catch what ?

Comment: It's because the Exception that you caught in your Aspect is 403 which propagates back as the response (If you don't wrap it) . The Object that you were sending is sent in the Response Body which is different from HTTP status of your response.